# Where is the absolute value function differentiable?

Tags: derivatives

I have that $f(x) = |x^2 -4x|$

What I've done is trying to define $f(x)$ with the zero values being 0 and 4. But not really sure if that's how I'm supposed to go about solving this.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$f(x)=|x^2-4x|=|x|\cdot |x-4|$$
and if $$x\geq 4$$ then $$f(x)=x(x-4)$$
if $$0\le x<4$$ then we have $$f(x)=x(4-x)$$
if $$x<0$$ we get $$f(x)=-x(4-x)$$
now can make a Image of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|x^2-4x|}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-(x^2-4x)}{x}=-\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x-4)=4$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{|x^2-4x|}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{(x^2-4x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x-4)=-4$$
What may we conclude about the differentiability of $f$ at $0$?
What about the other point $x=4$?

P.S. Recall that $|g(x)|=g(x)$ if $g(x)\geq 0$ and $|g(x)|=-g(x)$ otherwise.

Comment: So it's not differentiable at 0 because we get $4 != -4$ but at 4 I get $0 = 0$ so it's differentiable at 4?

Comment: @JohnDoe For $x=0$ you are correct. As regards $4$ you have to consider $ \lim_{x\to 4^+}\frac{f(x)-f(4)}{x-4}$ and $ \lim_{x\to 4^-}\frac{f(x)-f(4)}{x-4}$. Try again!

Comment: Oh right so then I get $4 != -4$ as well. So does that tell me that $f(x)$ isn't differentiable anywhere?

Comment: No, it is not differentiable just at $0$ and $4$, because to obtain different limits from the left and from the right we need a change of the sign of $x(x-4)$.

Comment: Ok everywhere except at 0 and 4 then? Isn't the ${x\to 0^+}$ supposed to be $(x^2 - 4x)$ and $x\to 0^-$ the $-(x^2 -4x)$ ? Or am I looking at the graph wrong

Comment: $(x^2−4x) =x(x-4)$ is negative in $(0,4)$. Hence $|x^2−4x|=-(x^2-4x)$ in a right neighborhood of $0$.